# spot when event is attached

Tags: vb.net, reflection, .net-2.0

I have the problem that an event in my program is called twice and i have no clue where to start to look for the problem.
I'm just curious if there is a way to spot the places when a method gets hooked to an event.
I can attach a method dynamically with AddHandler and i thought i read somewhere that in the final code WithEvents is replaced with AddHandler.
So if i have the code and the assemblies, can i use a tool like ilspy to find these calls in the code and how would i do that (i know that ilspy currently displays code in c# out, that shouldn't be the problem)?

Thanks in advance.